# How do i mock an external libraries' classes/functions such as yaml.load() or Box() in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, with-statement

How would i go about testing the following class and its functions?

```py
import yaml
from box import Box
from yaml import SafeLoader


class Config:
    def set_config_path(self):
        self.path = r"./config/datasets.yaml"
        return self.path

    def create_config(self):
        with open(r"./config/datasets.yaml") as f:
            self.config = Box(yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader))
        return self.config
```

These are the current tests I have created so far, but i am struggling with the final function:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch
from src.utils.config import Config


class TestConfig(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.path = r"./config/datasets.yaml"

    def test_set_config_path(self):
        assert Config.set_config_path(self) == self.path

    @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="data")
    def test_create_config(self, mock_file):
        assert open(self.path).read() == "data"
```

How would i go about testing/mocking the `Box()` and `yaml.load()` methods.

I have tried mocking where the `Box` and `yaml.load()` functions are used in the code - however i dont fully understand how this works.

Ideally I'd want to be able to pass a fake file to the `with open() as f:`, which then is read by `Box` and `yaml.load` to output a fake dictionary config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to remember about unit tests is that the goal is to test public interfaces of YOUR code. So to mock a third parties code is not really a good thing to do though in python it can be done but would be alot of monkey patching and other stuff.

Also creating and deleting files in a unit test is fine to do as well. So you could just create a test version of the `yaml` file and store it in the unit tests directory. During a test load the file and then do assertions to check that it was loaded properly and returned.

You wouldn't do a unit test checking if `Box` was initialized properly cause that should be in another test or test case. Unless its a third party then you would have to make sure it was initialized properly cause it's not your code.

So create a test file, `open` it and load it as `yaml` then pass it into `Box` constructor. Do assertions to make sure those steps completed properly. No need to mock `yaml` or `Box`.